# Copying text from a ClassNN

Tags: autohotkey

I have spent WAYY to much time on this and cant for the life of me figure it out.
I am using an old mapping program called "Streets and Trips" and there are pushpins that when you click them reveal information about that location. One of the pieces of info is the GPS which i need to copy.

When I use window spy it says that the area is a ClassNN: edit2

I want to copy that information but i have tried a few thing with no luck.

ControlGetText OutputVar, Edit2

as well as

WinGetText OutputVar, Edit2

i also tried to use 
Clipboard := OutputVart
to put the text to the clipboard. 
no luck

Comment: You're missing the window title in the first command. Try to fix that and if it doesn't work try running as admin. (Also for your second code WinGetText doesn't use that parameters.)

Answer (score 0):

I had to sleep on it because it was driving me NUTS! 
But I finally got it

```
ControlGetText, text, Edit2, R4 Map 12-18-18 - Microsoft Streets & Trips
```

What I don't understand is why there are NO examples of what OutputVar could be replaced with ANYWHERE on the AHK website. On a whim i found a snippet of code somewhere with the "text" in its place.